# Plotting a function dependent on $x/d$

Tags: plotting

I have a problem in plotting a function. The example code is as following:

```
d = 0.1;
M[x_] := ((x/d) - 0.4);
Plot[p[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {{0, d, 2d, 3d}, {1, 1}}]
```

I would like to have $d,\ 2d,\ 3d$ and so on the x-axis label at right positions, i.e. at $0.1,\ 0.2$ and so on. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like this? (ps. I assume your `M[x_]` is meant to be `p[x]`

```
 tick[min_, max_] := 
  Table[{i, Row[{Rationalize[i/d], "d"}], {.01, 0}, Black}, {i, 
    Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 10*d}];
d = 0.1;
maxRange = 10;
p[x_] := ((x/d) - 0.4);
Plot[p[x], {x, 0, maxRange}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {tick, None}}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 10], Automatic}, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

You can play with the tick styling as you want, change the number formatting, etc...